# Elasticseach no results for json query

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I am learning elasticsearch and following along with the tutorial. I uploaded three documents into an index. When I supply the following query:

```
curl 'localhost:9200/vehicles/_search?query=driver.name:Jon'
```

I as expected get back object two and object three. However when I try querying using json:

```
curl localhost:9200/vehicles/_search -d'

{
    "query":{
        "prefix":{
            "driver.name":"Jon"
}}}'
```

I get no results back. I am following the tutorial very closely, so I don't understand what the issue is. Any help would be really appreciated. The uploaded objects are below.

Thank you!

```
id:one
'{
    "color": "green",
    "driver": {
        "born":"1989-09-12",
        "name": "Ben"
},
    "make": "BMW",
    "model": "Aztek", 
    "value": 3000.0,
    "year": 2003
}'

id:two
'{
    "color": "black",
    "driver": {
        "born":"1934-09-08",
        "name": "Jon"
    },
    "make": "Mercedes",
    "model": "Benz", 
    "value": 10000.0,
    "year": 2012
}'

id:three
'{
    "color": "green",
    "driver": {
        "born":"1934-09-08",
        "name": "Jon"
    },
    "make": "BMW",
    "model": "Benz", 
    "value": 10000.0,
    "year": 2012
 }'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`prefix`-query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) "matches documents that have fields containing terms with a specified prefix (not analyzed)".

Note the "not analyzed"-part. Lucene is looking for anything starting with "Jon" in the index, but the standard analyzer lowercases terms. That is, "jon" is in the index, but "Jon" is not.

Thus, if you lowercase the text in your prefix-query, it should work. Here is a runnable example: https://www.found.no/play/gist/7629456

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly it. Searching 'jon' worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/vehicles/_search" -d '
{
  "query": {"query_string" : { "query" : "driver.name:Jon" }}
}'
```

In any case, If you are new to elasticsearch I really recommend you read the documentation because there are lots of types of queries. Besides, the results of queries also depends on how you index the documents, how you define the mapping, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the prefix query, you need to hit a non-analyzed field. In your mappings for driver.name, if you set "index" to "not_analyzed", you can use the prefix query. Otherwise, you should use a match query or something similar.